# Show only one character and hide the rest for sensitive data in .net core razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have display for my data like

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.UserName)
```

Result

```
  John
```

I want to show only one character and hide the rest for user name data.

Result that is required

```
 J######
```

Is there a quick way to display something like this, or will I have to write my own backend logic?

Comment: You could have a read-only property on your model that returns just the first letter and the remaining hidden? Something like this? `var hashes = new string('#', username.Length - 1);` `var filteredUsername = $"{username[0]}{hashes}";`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put `@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.UserName)` into div;
and change the content of div with `$(function(){})`:

```
<div id="UserName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)</div>
<script>
$(function () {
            var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').innerHTML;
            var characters = userName.split('');
            var newUserName = "";
            if (characters.length > 0) {
                newUserName = characters[0];
                for (var i = 1; i < characters.length; i++) {
                    newUserName += '#';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('UserName').innerHTML = newUserName;
        })
</script>
```